# How to close the Run window in TextMate 2?

Tags: macos, textmate

In TextMate 2, I can run the current file by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, and it will show in a new area under the text editor.

But how can I close it?

Answer (score 3):

You can click it and press command-W.

I haven't found any keyboard shortcut for closing it or moving focus to it though. If you set **Preferences > Projects > Show command output** to **New window**, you can close the window with command-W and move focus to it with command-`.